# How to get the value of dynamic textbox input

Tags: javascript, html

I created a function that dynamically creates textboxes, and I am getting the value of the first textbox because it's created in my HTML...

**but I can't get the values of any other textboxes from my `addInput` function. I would like to get the value in my `addQuestion` function like how I did for the testcases**.

```js
function addInput(divID) {
  if (counter == limit) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "Case " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]' id='case'>";
    document.getElementById(divID).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;


  }
}

function addQuestion() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var testcases = document.getElementById("testcases").value;

  var myJSONObject = {
    "testcases": testcases
  };

  console.log(JSON.stringify(myJSONObject));

  request.open("POST", "createQuestion_middle.php", true);

  request.send(JSON.stringify(myJSONObject));

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      var return_data = request.responseText;
      console.log(return_data);
      /* window.location.assign("insFront.php"); */
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cases">
  Case 1<br><input type="text" id="testcases" name="myInputs[]">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add another test case" onClick="addInput('cases');">
```

As you can see, the value for "Case 1" can send, but not for "Case 2". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some erros:

You cannot have more than one element with same `ID`. In **addInput** function, the `ID` os hard-coded, and will be the same for all elements added:

```
<input type='text' name='myInputs[]' id='case'>
```

In **addQuestion** function, you're trying to get element by ID 'testecases', but new elements have id='case':

```
var testcases = document.getElementById("testcases").value
```

To fix the errors, remove ID from dynamically added inputs, and try to get elements by name:

```
var testcases = document.getElementsByName("myInputs[]")
```

Comment: hi thanks for replying back. How would i get the value of all the inputs so that I can send it in `myJSONObject`.

Comment: use `forEach` to loop the elements:  `testcases.forEach((i) => console.log(i.value) );`  you can get `i.value` and add to an array and serialize, or build a string with values

Answer (score 0):

You can select all inputs that are children of #cases with querySelectorAll:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#cases > input')
console.log(inputs[0].value);
console.log(inputs[1].value);
```

If you want to put all values into an array and send it:

```
const inputValues = [...inputs].map(input => input.value);
// ...
const myJSONObject = { testcases: inputValues };
```